# custom input field on product grid in admin magento 2

Tags: input, customization, user-input, magento2, product

I am making custom module where am attaching to customers to products with the help of product grid

**See screenshot two tabs**

[image]

and in select product tab m selecting products

**Tab 2**

[image]

while selecting products I want to add one custom input field on all product where I can enter value and that value will store in my database.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. The fastet way is add the new custom attribute to the products and use it. You can add new attribute via Admin Panel or from `Namespace/Module/Setup/UpgradeData.php` (or install) file in your custom module (which is better in my opinion). Then this attribute will be visible in all products in BE and value'll be available in FE via `$product->getData('attr_name')`.

If you want to show this attribute input only for assigned products (not for all) -> then it is most complex, but usually it's not problem that product has additional input.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I implement this only for assigned product?